# Scope's constraints are ignored in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

It looks like whenever I have `get` with constraints inside `scope`, the `scope`'s constraints are ignored:

Here route is recognized:

```
scope '(/:optional_slug)', constraints: ->(req) { raise 'first constraint!' } do
  get '/:category/:slug(/:locale)' => 'public/posts#show', 
    constraints: ->(req) { true }
end
```

Here `second constraints` is raised:

```
scope '(/:optional_slug)', constraints: ->(req) { raise 'first constraint!' } do
  get '/:category/:slug(/:locale)' => 'public/posts#show', 
    constraints: ->(req) { raise 'second constraint!' }
end
```

And the `first constraint!` is raised only when I remove constraints from `get`

```
scope '(/:optional_slug)', constraints: ->(req) { raise 'first constraint!' } do
  get '/:category/:slug(/:locale)' => 'public/posts#show'
end
```

I can't find it anywhere in the docs explaining such behavior. Am I missing something or is it a bug?